# Trouble saving websocket json message to variable

Tags: python, websocket

I'm trying to open a websocket on AAX exchange for the BTC market price and save it to a variable so I can use it in my code but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

AAX API docs:
https://www.aax.com/apidoc/index.html?python#mark-price

This code works:

```py
import websocket, json

market = "BTCUSDTFP"

ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws.connect("wss://realtime.aax.com/marketdata/v2/")
ws.send('{"e": "subscribe", "stream":"' + market + '@mark"}')

while True:
    price = json.loads(ws.recv())
    print(price)
```

I get this response:

```
{'e': 'system', 'status': [{'all': 'active'}]}
{'e': 'reply', 'status': 'ok', 'subscribe': 'BTCUSDTFP@mark'}
{'T': 1668124800000, 'e': 'BTCUSDTFP@mark', 'i': '17264.84999999', 'p': '17282.07000000', 'r': '0.0014617609', 't': 1668105126903}
{'T': 1668124800000, 'e': 'BTCUSDTFP@mark', 'i': '17271.22000000', 'p': '17288.45000000', 'r': '0.0014616797', 't': 1668105127922}
{'T': 1668124800000, 'e': 'BTCUSDTFP@mark', 'i': '17271.24000000', 'p': '17288.47000000', 'r': '0.0014616046', 't': 1668105128970}
```

But when I do this:

```py
print(price['p'])
```

I get this:

```
KeyError: 'p'
```

Which makes sense because the initial message response doesn't contain a key called 'p'.

But I'm confused about where to go from here.  How do I ignore the initial two messages and access only the specific key that I want?

Comment: `if 'p' in y:` / `print(y['p'])`

Comment: Thank you.  You replied before I edited the post to: `if 'p' in price:
        print(price['p'])`

Comment: And that's the fix.  Your question is answered, right?

Comment: Yes it is.  Do I have to mark it as answered or something?

Comment: No, just making sure it was understood.  ;)